# IPhone 4: Not killable background application

Tags: iphone

IOS4 allow application to run in background. Is it possible to have an application running in the background and not killable without a password?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is no.

IOS can always kill your app if it doesn't behave or if memory is needed. Likewise the user can always kill the app if he feels like it.

I don't really understand why you would want this feature anyway?

Comment: security or website monitoring.  Advanced child-protection?

Comment: If you're looking to do that kind of stuff you should probably look at Android or some other open platform. You could possibly do it on a jailbroken iPhone if it's just for personal use. I don't think they'll ever allow anything like that on App Store.

Answer (score 0):

No. And background tasks are quite limit in their use cases. With exception of location services and audio things, its essential fast app switching / app pausing.